# How to change location name in Maps intent

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

Is there a way to specify name for a location within the Google Maps intent rather than displaying "Unnamed location"?

```
val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=55.5, -4.3")
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
mCtx.startActivity(mapIntent)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the location has no name on Google Maps, no. You'd need to [add](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846?hl=en&ref_topic=3257381) or [edit](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7084895?hl=en&ref_topic=3257381) the place.

You can also use the `label` parameter to search for a location. Check out Google's example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#location_search):

```
// Display a label at the location of Google's Sydney office
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=-33.8666,151.1957(Google+Sydney)");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Hope this helps!